# How to pop initial route using go_router in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I'm exploring `go_router` as navigation solution for my Flutter app and facing a simple scenario I'm struggling with.

I have initial route `/home` that navigate screen to HomePage. Inside HomePage I have a close button to just simply close HomePage, which is the first stack of the screens.

I was expecting that I can do something exactly the same to what I do using standard Navigator: `Navigator.of(context).pop()` that will close entire app since I'm in the first stack of the route.

But when I call `context.pop()` it gives me the following error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following GoError was thrown while handling a gesture:
There is nothing to pop

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      GoRouterDelegate.pop (package:go_router/src/delegate.dart:94:5)
#1      GoRouter.pop (package:go_router/src/router.dart:492:20)
#2      GoRouterHelper.pop (package:go_router/src/misc/extensions.dart:71:65)
#3      HomeView.build.<anonymous closure> (package:navigation/home_view.dart:25:33)
#4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1096:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:276:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:163:27)
#10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:464:20)
#11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
#12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:336:11)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
#14     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
#15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
#17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:164:13)
#18     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:361:7)
#19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#94750
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(165.4, 119.6)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(31.6, 25.6)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

How can I do closing my app just like what I do using Navigator.of(context).pop() in `go_router`?

Comment: You can try this one. Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

Comment: This just avoid the crash to happen but doesn't solve my need to pop from initial route and close the app

Answer (score 0):

you could use `SystemNavigator` to handle with app navigation stack

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemNavigator.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention that i was trying this way as well but i'm actually looking for go_router solution for this. Since it's supported by Navigator 1.0 i was expecting that go_router should have proper way to handle this scenario.